# UIScrollView with paging not working ok

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have implement a scrollview with paging but it not work ok. For every view of the scrollview I must populate a tableview with certain values. Even if the values are correct received all the views are identical (the last view is the view on every subview of scrollview) Where is my mistake?

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size.width * [vehiculesEnvisages count], vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;


    vehiculesEnvisagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gamme", @"Usage",@"Délai d'echart",@"Type d'achart",@"Financement", nil];


    for (int i=0; i<[vehiculesEnvisages count];i++){
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
    }

     NSLog(@"views %@",[vehiculesenvisagesScrollView subviews]);

    self.pageControlVehiculeEnvisages.numberOfPages=[vehiculesEnvisages count];
    self.pageControlVehiculeEnvisages.currentPage=0;    
}

- (void) loadScrollViewWithPage: (int) page {

    NSLog(@"%d",page);
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= [vehiculesEnvisages count]) return;

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *oneview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 

    tableViewVehiculesEnvisages=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0, 320, 233) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableViewVehiculesEnvisages.bounces=NO;
    tableViewVehiculesEnvisages.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [tableViewVehiculesEnvisages setDelegate:self];
    [tableViewVehiculesEnvisages setDataSource:self];        

    self.gammeString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"gamme"];
    self.usageString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"usage"];
    self.delaiString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"delai"];
    self.typeString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"achat"];
    self.financementString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"financement"];

    [oneview addSubview:tableViewVehiculesEnvisages];

    NSLog(@"gamme%@", self.gammeString);
    [self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView addSubview:oneview];
    [oneview release];

}
```

where `gammeString,usageString,delaiString,typeString,financementString` contains the text that will be set to some labels on a cell of tableview.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"] autorelease];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            gammeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            gammeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, -4, 150, 50);
            gammeLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            gammeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            gammeLabel.text = self.gammeString;  
            [cell.contentView addSubview: [gammeLabel autorelease]];   
        }

        if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            usageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            usageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, -4, 150, 50);
            usageLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            usageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            usageLabel.text = self.usageString;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: [usageLabel autorelease]];
        }

        if(indexPath.row==2)
        {
            delaiLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            delaiLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
            delaiLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            delaiLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            delaiLabel.text = self.delaiString;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: [delaiLabel autorelease]];

        }

        if(indexPath.row==3)
        {
            typeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
            typeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            typeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            typeLabel.text =self.typeString;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: [typeLabel autorelease]];

        }

        if(indexPath.row==4)
        {
            financementLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            financementLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
            financementLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            financementLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            financementLabel.text = self.financementString;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: [financementLabel autorelease]];

        }

    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [vehiculesEnvisagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How are your data source methods implemented? (especially the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method)

Comment: I have a method where I receive this array from a php script. it is ok, it looks like this : [{"gamme":"Audi R8 Spyder","usage":"Priv\u00e9","delai":"Plus de 12 mois","achat":"Neuf","financement":"Comptant"},{"gamme":"Audi A1","usage":"","delai":"","achat":"","financement":""},{"gamme":"Audi A1","usage":"","delai":"","achat":"","financement":""},{"gamme":"Audi R8 Spyder","usage":"Priv\u00e9","delai":"Plus de 12 mois","achat":"Neuf","financement":"Comptant"}] and I take the information from it

Comment: From what I understand `vehiculesEnvisagesArray` doesn't change at all and it is the data source for all your table views, isn't it? So I would expect the same values to be populated on all your table views unless of course you change the data in the array when the user scrolls between pages.

Comment: the vehiculesEnvisagesArray must be the same for every tableview... the text from labels must be changed when I change the page

Comment: How are you changing those values i.e. the value of `self.gammeString` and similar strings?

Comment: gammeString is different for every page. here i set it : self.gammeString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"gamme"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my issue : I use a NSMutableArray instead of a NSString and it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) loadScrollViewWithPage: (int) page {

NSLog(@"%d",page);
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= [vehiculesEnvisages count]) return;

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.frame.size;

UIView *oneview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 

tableViewVehiculesEnvisages=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0, 320, 233) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableViewVehiculesEnvisages.tag=page;
tableViewVehiculesEnvisages.bounces=NO;
tableViewVehiculesEnvisages.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[tableViewVehiculesEnvisages setDelegate:self];
[tableViewVehiculesEnvisages setDataSource:self];        

 [oneview addSubview:tableViewVehiculesEnvisages];

NSLog(@"gamme%@", self.gammeString);
[self.vehiculesenvisagesScrollView addSubview:oneview];
[oneview release];
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"] autorelease];
}

    [self setTextt:tableView.tag];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        gammeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        gammeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, -4, 150, 50);
        gammeLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        gammeLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        gammeLabel.text = self.gammeString;  
        [cell.contentView addSubview: [gammeLabel autorelease]];   
    }

    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        usageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        usageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, -4, 150, 50);
        usageLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        usageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        usageLabel.text = self.usageString;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: [usageLabel autorelease]];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        delaiLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        delaiLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
        delaiLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        delaiLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        delaiLabel.text = self.delaiString;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: [delaiLabel autorelease]];

    }

    if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        typeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
        typeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        typeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        typeLabel.text =self.typeString;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: [typeLabel autorelease]];

    }

    if(indexPath.row==4)
    {
        financementLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        financementLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 150, -4, 150, 50);
        financementLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        financementLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        financementLabel.text = self.financementString;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: [financementLabel autorelease]];

    }

[[cell textLabel] setText: [vehiculesEnvisagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

return cell;
}   



-(void)setTextt:(int)page
{
self.gammeString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"gamme"];
self.usageString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"usage"];
self.delaiString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"delai"];
self.typeString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"achat"];
self.financementString=[[vehiculesEnvisages objectAtIndex:page]valueForKey:@"financement"];

}
```

Replace your code with this code,You defiantly get solution.

Comment: i get error at line [self setText:(vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.contentOffset.x/320)];

Comment: Ya, i pass page number over there.so pass it from ur side,u get solution over there...!

Comment: (vehiculesenvisagesScrollView.contentOffset.x is null

Comment: Now made some change in code please replace ur code with this.